# OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW option for cvCalculateOpticalFlowFarneback

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I am working on a project using OpenCV and I am using the optical flow algorithm cvCalculateOpticalFlowFarneback to get the optical flow on my video.

I have been reading the documentation and even been looking into the source a bit and there is an option you can feed to the algorithm: OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW

I have been playing around with it but I cannot see any difference in speed or accuracy. So my question is:

What does the option do? Have you experienced any differences in using it, compared to not? (good or bad)

Also, I came across a code comment when looking at some implementation saying that this option should be avoided as there is a bug in it. I couldn't fine it anywhere else but it makes me a bit nervous (especially when including into production software).

Any comments are apprechiated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OpenCV documentation for cvCalculateOpticalFlowFarneback](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cv-calcopticalflowfarneback) says:

> OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW Use the input flow as the initial flow approximation

Which means: If you fill in the output parameter flow with your estimate of the flow then this function will use the flow you give as an initial estimate, just as you suspect. You'll only see any real difference if you can give it a reasonable estimate of the flow as input. Otherwise this will have no effect or even make it worse. You can easily test the effect if you have a video sequence where the camera is moving at a constant speed:

- For the first two images, compute the flow without the parameter.
- For subsequent images use the flow computed for the previous pair as input for the new calculation with the OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW parameter. And calculate the flow without it as well.
- Compare the resulting flow and the time it takes. This should show you the effect of the paramter.

Since (if I understand correctly) Gunnar Farneback’s algorithm is some optimization algorithm to find optical flow it is prone to getting stuck in a local maximum, so a good initialization can presumably help you find a better global maximum for the flow, so the effect of the parameter should be a better flow output. Not necessarily faster.

Regarding possible bugs in the implementation and production use (note: I haven't looked at the actual source):

- If the optical flow you find without it is acceptable for your needs, don't use it.
- If you test the influence of the parameter and you find it helps, test some more until you are confident that it helps and use it.
- You could ask about the bug on the [OpenCV mailinglist](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/), but I would advise you to first do some testing and some more code-reading before you try.